# Subclassing in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift, subclassing, exc-bad-instruction

I'm making an RPG-type game, in which you can choose the attack your user has. I'm trying to make it so that I have a superclass named "Projectile", where general variables are described, and subclasses that change the variables. But whenever I override the value of the variables, I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Projectile: SKNode {


    var texture: SKTexture!
    var projectileBody = SKSpriteNode()
    var projectile: SKEmitterNode!
    var negativeEffect: DefaultNegativeEffect!


    func setUpValues() {

        texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bokeh.png")
        projectileBody = SKSpriteNode()
        projectile = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "testbokeh.sks")
        negativeEffect = DefaultNegativeEffect(runningSpeed: 0)


    }

     override init() {
        super.init()
        projectileBody.texture = texture
        projectileBody.size = texture.size()
        projectileBody.position = self.position
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        projectile.position = self.position
        self.addChild(projectileBody)
        self.addChild(projectile)

    }


    func update() {

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class FireBall: Projectile {

    override func setUpValues() {

        texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "spark5.png")
        projectileBody = SKSpriteNode()
        projectile = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "testbokeh.sks")
        negativeEffect = DefaultNegativeEffect(runningSpeed: 0)

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling setUpValues() prior to accessing texture, projectile, or negativeEffect?

Comment: I wasn't until you guys told me! @dustincarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like class `Projectile` calls `super.init()` before setting its own properties, and never calls `setUpValues()` at all, meaning your variable properties never have values.

In the `Fireball` subclass the setUpValues function still isn't being called, and you don't have a separate init() function, so it's the same problem: the values aren't ever being set.

The rules for initialization in Swift are a bit different from Obj-C in that you need to initialize all stored instance properties before calling super.init(), and have to consider how you handle inherited properties as well to ensure you have a fully/properly initialized object.

From Apple's [Swift Programming Guide:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

1. A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.
2. A designated initializer must delegate up to a superclass initializer before assigning a value to an inherited property. If it doesn’t, the new value the designated initializer assigns will be overwritten by the superclass as part of its own initialization.

Comment: Declaring with ! also initializes the values to nil.

Comment: Thank you! But I think doing what @dustincarr said is better, because when I tried the '?' I was getting errors telling me SKTexture doesn't have the member named 'size'

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part - implicitly unwrapping during declaration (as you did) still defaults to `nil` and allows you to skip the step of forced unwrapping later, which you would've had to do (`texture!.size` for example). Glad you were able to solve it!